# Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql

```
set @PropertyList='select distinct 
        P.PropertyName 
    from 
        Property P 
    join 
        ContactAssignment CA on CA.AssociatedObjectId = p.PropertyID
    left join 
        contactsubtype CS on CS.ContactSubTypeName = CA.SubType
    where 
        ' + Charindex('' + cast('' + PropertyID + '' as varchar(8000)) + '', @array) >  0 + '
        and Cs.ContactSubTypeID not in (' + @Contactindselect + ')'
```

Comment: what are these quotes for?

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.  Please explain what you want to do.  And why are you using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select
  distinct P.PropertyName
from
  Property P
  join ContactAssignment CA on CA.AssociatedObjectId = p.PropertyID
  left join contactsubtype CS on CS.ContactSubTypeName = CA.SubType
where
  '+Charindex(''+cast(''+PropertyID+'' as varchar(8000))+'', @array)  >  0+'
  and Cs.ContactSubTypeID not in ('+@Contactindselect+')
```